# Inno Setup Unicode shows rtf EULA incorrect

Tags: unicode, installation, inno-setup

I use Inno Setup 5.5.9 Unicode to create installation package for my app.
To show EULA I use this line in *.iss:

```
LicenseFile=eula.rtf
```

But on some machines the EULA windows shows the text as escape codes, not the text itself:

```
{\rtf1\adeflang1037\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\ ...
```

Even more interesting that I use the same rtf file for several installations. And on one of them the installation shows the rtf EULA as a text and in others as an escape codes on the same machine. The *.iss are the same except installed files.

Is there some way to be sure that my rtf EULA file will be shown without problem on any machine?
A don't want to use plain text since in this case I lose formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. The `rtf` file was saved with Word. The file had size 45k and contained tons of waste. After opening and resaving the file with WordPad the size reduced to 10k and now the file contains only relevant tags and text. It looks that `Inno Setup` just unable to parse Word's monstrous output.